# Wrong Date in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, mongoose

I don't know why but when I create a new document in mongoose the date isn't the actual date.

This is my schema :

```
var WhispSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text : String,
    created_at : {type : Date, index : true},
    pos : {latitude: Number, longitude: Number},
    created_by : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : "UserSchema"},
    upvote : {type : Number, default : 0},
    downvote : {type : Number, default : 0},
    comment : [CommentSchema]
});

WhispSchema.pre("save", function (next){
    var currentDate = new Date();

    if(!this.created_at)
    {
        this.created_at = currentDate;
    }
    next();
});
```

Why the "created_at" field is not the date of creation of my document ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to define your schema as below

```
 var WhispSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
text : String,
created_at : {type : Date, index : true,default:Date.now()},
pos : {latitude: Number, longitude: Number},
created_by : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : "UserSchema"},
upvote : {type : Number, default : 0},
downvote : {type : Number, default : 0},
comment : [CommentSchema]
 });
```

in case you want to use the plugin to add created time you can use it as follow

```
 var WhispSchema = require('mongoose-timestamp');
 WhispSchema.plugin(timestamps);
```

//use npm install to install them

Comment: It's ok for the date but not for the hours.

Comment: When I create a document the date shows an hour late, like this (I just created it now) "2015-12-07T10:11:38.617Z"

Comment: Date.now() takes your system's date please cross check the date of your system.

Comment: The date and hour of my server is good I checked it "Mon Dec  7 11:15:07 CET 2015"

Comment: okay  do like this var now = new Date();
db.data.save( { date: now,
                offset: now.getTimezoneOffset() } );

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97183/discussion-between-johnybro-and-mayank).

Comment: Can you tell me how override with your plugin plz.

Answer (score 0):

You could just define:

```
created_at : {type: Date, index : true, default: Date.now}
```

Every time a document is created this will set the created_at property to the current date.